# Ay (2017) vs Amari (2016) for information geometry

Tags: inference, references, information-geometry

I am interested in learning information geometry in detail with a focus on applications, and am currently considering two main texts: [Amari (2016)'s "Information Geometry and Its Applications"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-4-431-55978-8) and [Ay et al. (2017)'s "Information Geometry"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-56478-4#reviews). My main interest is in applications to statistical inference, and my background in differential/Riemannian geometry is basically none.

How do these two books for someone with poor experience in differential/Riemannian geometry? What do they cover that the other doesn't, or is there a lot of overlap?

Comment: Why not [Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms](http://www.inference.org.uk/mackay/itila/book.html) by David MacKay?

Comment: @mhdadk I'm not sure that book covers the same field as those in my question, since that involves Information Theory as opposed to Information Geometry. Maybe I've misunderstood it from its table of contents, though?